# what is syntax to define a rails 4 scope in terms of other scopes (use block, Proc, or neither?)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, scope

I am migrating a rather large app from rails 3.2 to 4.0, and am still at the stage of making all the little edits needed to get specs passing again...

When I define a scope in terms of other scopes, do I need a Proc, or just  block, or neither? The Rails docs appear to be silent on the subject

For example if I have migrated these two to the Proc syntax:

```
scope :foo_scope, -> { where("foo_state = ?", "foo1") }
scope :bar_scope, -> { where("bar_state = ?", "bar1") }
```

would I migrate the following:

```
scope :both_scopes, foo_scope.bar_scope # Rails 3.2 syntax
```

to:

```
scope :both_scopes, -> { foo_scope.bar_scope }
  or
scope :both_scopes, { foo_scope.bar_scope }
  or leave it:
scope :both_scopes, foo_scope.bar_scope
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems to work if you do it with Proc (just like other scopes), eg:

```
scope :both_scopes, -> { foo_scope.bar_scope }
```